# How to visually compare two HTML documents?

Tags: html, winforms, webview2

I am creating a Windows Forms application in order to compare two HTML documents. The first one is retrieved from an external source and contains some structure mistakes. So an algorithm is applied to transform the HTML text into an optimized document and that corresponds to the second document to compare. After that, I want to visually compare the optimized document to the first one and display differences if they are ones.

I created a form with two webview2 controls, where the first one displays the first HTML document. A button is used to transform HTML text and then I would like to know what is the best way to perform a visual comparison. The ideal behavior would be for the second webview2 to display the transformed HTML document and to display differences with a special color for example.

So my first approach is to use this function:

```
await webview2.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("window.print();");
```

And perfom a visual comparison of the two screenshots, but I saw that the control of the print popup window is not possible for the moment with the webview2 component.

So do you think there is a better way to accomplish that? Are there any more suitable components or tools to perform this comparison?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Visual comparison is very hard (unless you simply look at it), because it depends on each and every stylesheet rule applied. I think your method of having them next to each other is the best solution, otherwisw it would require some AI.

Comment: Thanks @PoulBak for your answer. In my case, stylesheet rules are not modified so normally the second document should look the same. Could this simplify the comparison process ?

Comment: Not really. Say you create a new `<div>`element, then stylesheet rules are applied to that element (even when the rules haven't changed).

Comment: CoreWebView2.CapturePreviewAsync will give you back an image of what's in the webview2 and may work better than 'window.print'. I don't know about the rest.

Comment: Thanks a lot @DavidRisney, it seems to match what I want. I will check this function!

Answer (score 0):

In the algorithm, could you add the changed element ids to a list, take that list, and then change the CSS via javascript to highlight the elements in the list.

I'm working on an implementation of it now to see if its viable.

Comment: It's a good idea thank you @Charles, but it will not work in my case because a lot of HTML elements will be modified. But the goal of this algorithm is to have a more correct HTML syntax, the style of the visual result doesn't have to be changed. That's why I need a visual comparison, to confirm if the optimized document looks like the first one even if HTML is different.